# C++ problem with virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, virtual

I need to write something in C++. I have problem with virtual functions.

For example, in header file `Human.h` I have this:

```
class Human
{
    public:
        virtual int Age();
        Human();
        ~Human();
}
```

In `Human.cpp` file I have this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Human.h"

int Human::Age()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get these compile errors:

```
Error    4    error C2371: 'Human::Age' : redefinition; different basic types    c:\users\jan\desktop\testc\testc\human.cpp    5    1    TestC
Error    3    error C2556: 'Human Human::Age(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int Human::Age(void)'    c:\users\jan\desktop\testc\testc\human.cpp    5    1    TestC
Error    2    error C2628: 'Human' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)    c:\users\jan\desktop\testc\testc\human.cpp    4    1    TestC
```

Comment: In general, if you have any virtual functions in a class that has a constructor and destructor (e.g. a non-abstract class), you will also want to declare your destructor as virtual.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have forgotten to end the class definition with a `;`

It should read

```
class Human
{
public:
    virtual int Age();
    Human();
    ~Human();
};
```

This will likely make the error go away. Also, always read the compiler's output: `Error   2   error C2628: 'Human' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)   c:\users\jan\desktop\testc\testc\human.cpp  4   1   TestC`

Comment: Sory it was my mistake, in C# you don’t must put ; on end of the class and also I was tired. Thank for help, I am dumb :(